# Connect to a queue on JBoss EAP6 from Camel

Tags: java, jboss, apache-camel, jms, jboss6.x

I have a HornetQ JMS queue set on JBoss EAP6, in the standalone.xml file.

```
<hornetq-server>
[...]
    <jms-connection-factories>
        <connection-factory name="RemoteConnectionFactory">
            <connectors>
                <connector-ref connector-name="netty"/>
            </connectors>
            <entries>
                <entry name="java:jboss/exported/jms/RemoteConnectionFactory"/>
            </entries>
        </connection-factory>
    </jms-connection-factories>

    <jms-destinations>
        <jms-queue name="WorkflowExecution">
            <entry name="/queue/MyQueue"/>
            <entry name="java:jboss/exported/queue/MyQueue"/>
        </jms-queue>
    </jms-destinations>
</hornetq-server>
```

The queue works fine, and I can send messages on it using tools like Hermes JMS.

I'm working on a standalone client application, running in Fuse 4.4, that has to send a message to the queue via a Camel route but I can't figure out how to set the connector in the configuration.

This is what I tried to set in the camel-context.xml file:

```
<bean id="jmsinjection" class="org.apache.camel.component.jms.JmsComponent">
  <property name="connectionFactory">
    <bean class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
      <property name="jndiName" value="jms/RemoteConnectionFactory" />
      <property name="jndiEnvironment">
        <props>
          <prop key="java.naming.provider.url">remote://myEAPurl:port</prop>
          <prop key="java.naming.factory.initial">org.jboss.naming.remote.client.InitialContextFactory</prop>
        </props>
      </property>
    </bean>
  </property>
</bean>
```

And the exception I get:

> Error creating bean with name 'jmsinjection' defined in URL [bundle://79.37:0/META-INF/spring/camel-context.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.ConversionNotSupportedException: Failed to convert property value of type 'org.hornetq.jms.client.HornetQJMSConnectionFactory' to required type 'javax.jms.ConnectionFactory' for property 'connectionFactory'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type [org.hornetq.jms.client.HornetQJMSConnectionFactory] to required type [javax.jms.ConnectionFactory] for property 'connectionFactory': no matching editors or conversion strategy found

According to the javadoc, `HornetQJMSConnectionFactory` implements `javax.jms.QueueConnectionFactory` which extends `javax.jms.ConnectionFactory`, so I don't get why I get this exception.

I spent hours scraping JBoss forum and doc but can't find a way to make it work.

What is wrong in my camel configuration? How to fix it?

Comment: have you tried an explicit conversion?

Comment: @FranciscoMelojunior could you explain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is due to the OSGi class-loader.

Fuse ESB already has a version of `javax.jms.ConnectionFactory` loaded in the classpath.

Adding the `jboss-client.jar` does add the `HornetQJMSConnectionFactory` to the classpath but also another version of the `ConnectionFactory`.

The solution is to add all the following dependencies to the bundle and remove the `jboss-client.jar` as indicated on [this page](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/jboss_enterprise_application_platform/6/html/migration_guide/sect-hornetq_changes):

```
hornetq-core
hornetq-jms
jboss-ejb-client
jboss-logging
jboss-logmanager
jboss-marshalling
jboss-marshalling-river
jboss-remote-naming
jboss-remoting
jboss-sasl
netty
remoting-jmx
xnio-api
xnio-nio
```

You can find all those dependencies with the correct version directly on your JBoss EAP instance repository. Names may be a bit different.